# Vertically aligning an input and an item in a top menu bar

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu bar at the top of my page called `.top-utility-bar` and in this I'd like to have a search box, a sign in link and a cart status.

I've made this quickly but I'm having some issues aligning the input box with the a links on the menu like so:
[image: unaligned menu bar]

I'd like it so the other items align with it vertically.

I've been trying to get it working for days but still no luck. Am I doing anything wrong that's obvious?

HTML:

```
<div class="top-utility-bar">
  <div class="right-top">
    <ul class="top-list">
      <li class="top-li">
        Hello <a href="/account">{{ customer.first_name }}</a>! {{ 'Log out' | customer_logout_link }}
    </li>
    <li class="top-li">
      <a href="/cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart icon"></i> {{ cart.item_count }} {{ cart.item_count | pluralize: 'item', 'items' }} ({{ cart.total_price | money }})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="top-li">  
      <form action="/search" method="get" class="search-form" role="search">
        <input name="q" type="search" id="search-field" placeholder="&#xF002; SEARCH" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" />
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-utility-bar input, .top-utility-bar a, .top-utility-bar i, .top-utility-bar {
  color: {{ settings.utility_bar_text_color }};
  background-color: {{ settings.utility_bar_color }};
}

.top-utility-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.top-list {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none outside none;
}

.top-li {
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you literally just want to move the search box up slightly, so that it's vertically centered with the basket and login button?

Comment: @Stormie yes! sorry if I worded it a bit funnily, it was kind of hard to describe haha

Comment: Paulie beat me to it, but that should absolutely fix your issue :)

Comment: @Ruby Just a question, did you try using CSS property `vertical-align:middle` on the search box?

Comment: @AhsN Yeah thought I'd tried everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than floating the `li`, float the whole `ul` and use `display:inline-block` on the `li`

Note: the original float was reversing the order of the `li` so I have changed that reflect the visual order according with the source order.

```css
.top-utility-bar input,
.top-utility-bar a,
.top-utility-bar i,
.top-utility-bar {
  color: {
    {
      settings.utility_bar_text_color
    }
  }
  ;
  background-color: {
    {
      settings.utility_bar_color
    }
  }
  ;
}
.top-utility-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.top-list {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: right;
}
.top-li {
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-utility-bar">
  <div class="right-top">
    <ul class="top-list">
      <li class="top-li">
        <form action="/search" method="get" class="search-form" role="search">
          <input name="q" type="search" id="search-field" placeholder="&#xF002; SEARCH" value="Alue" />
        </form>
      </li>
      <li class="top-li"><a>Item Count</a>
      </li>
      <li class="top-li">
        Hello <a href="/account">First Name</a>
      </li>


    </ul>
```

Comment: It looks better... but it's still not dead on aligned. Will font size have anything to do with it? http://i57.tinypic.com/167801g.png

Comment: I had something already on the searchbox but fixed it now. Much love <3